# inner join mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

i have 3 tables

**login** - user_id, username

**project** - project_id, project_name

**task** - task_id, project_id, task_giver, task_receiver, task_content

*where task_giver and task_receiver has the user_id from login table*

MY QUERY :

```
SELECT login.username, project.project_name, tasks.task_content, tasks.task_giver
  FROM tasks
  JOIN login ON login.user_id = tasks.task_receiver 
  JOIN project ON tasks.project_id = project.project_id
 ;
```

But I am not getting the `task_givers` name getting only id.
How can I get his name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JOIN` the `login` table one more time like so:

```
SELECT 
  receivers.username 'Task receiver',
  givers.username 'Task giver', 
  p.project_name, 
  t.task_content
FROM tasks t
INNER JOIN login   receivers ON receivers.user_id = t.task_receiver 
INNER JOIN login   givers    ON givers.user_id    = t.task_giver
INNER JOIN project p         ON t.project_id      = p.project_id
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo with some sample data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1dbdc/2)

Answer (score 0):

You have to `JOIN` login table twice (to task_receiver and to task_giver)